# How to track movement of second finger

Tags: android, android-canvas, touch-event

How to set second finteger to track his movement? I found just second finger down coordinatesand second finger up coordinates:

Here is my code:

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    X = (int) ev.getX();
    Y = (int) ev.getY();

    switch (ev.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        TXdown = (int) ev.getX();
        TYdown = (int) ev.getY();

        invalidate();

        break;

    }


    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {



        premik_w = (int) ev.getX()-TXdown+premik_w;
        premik_h = (int) ev.getY()-TYdown+premik_h;

        TXdown = (int) ev.getX();
        TYdown = (int) ev.getY();
        invalidate();
        break;

    }

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:{
             drugPrstXP = (int)ev.getX();
             drugPrstYP = (int)ev.getY(); 

    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        premik_w = (int) ev.getX()-TXdown+premik_w;
        premik_h = (int) ev.getY()-TYdown+premik_h;
        invalidate();

        break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

So pls someone tell me how to track coordinates of second finger and simultaneously of first finger. Cuz I like to do zoom and need movement of this to fingers.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) that will help you.

The methods you are looking for are:

getPointerId(int)

findPointerIndex(int)